# Function is not define

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js

Here is my code :

```js
// And my javascript file verbatims.js :
class Verbatims {
    
      list() {
        return ["c'est super", "j'aime pas", "ça marche bien"];
      }
    }
    
    module.exports = Verbatims;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

 <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta content="X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">        
        
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.18/vue.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/src/verbatims.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
        
  <title>My Project</title>
 </head>

 <body>
        <div id="PRISME_data">
            Le nombre de requête est de  : {{ nb_request }}<br>
            <button v-on:click="change">Change value</button>
            <button v-on:click="stop">Arrêter</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            let app = new Vue({
                el:'#PRISME_data',
                data: {
                    nb_request: "toto",
                    ite: 0
                },
                methods: {
                    change: function() {
                        changeNbRequest()
                    },
                    stop: function() {
                        clearInterval()
                    }
                }
            });

            changeNbRequest = function() {
                var timer = setInterval(function() {
                    let verbatim = new Verbatims().list()[ite];
                }, 5000);
            }
        </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I try to display my page with my node server I have this error :

Uncaught ReferenceError: Verbatims is not defined at index:45

on this line : `let verbatim = new Verbatims().list()[ite];`

I don't see why, I have try a lot of things but nothing work ! Do you have any idea ?

Thank you :)

Comment: `module.exports = Verbatims;` is this the content of the line number 45?

Comment: No sorry I forgot to precise! the error is on this line : `let verbatim = new Verbatims().list()[ite];`

Comment: Have you confirmed (using the Network tab of the developer tools) that `verbatims.js` is loading successfully? Are there any previous errors on the Console before the one you quoted?

Comment: verbatims.js is loading successfully and there isn't an previous errors on the console before this one.

Answer (score 0):

This might be happening because of the following:

- The verbatims.js file is not loading in the browser because of
  wrong path.
- The verbatims.js file that reached the browser does
  not contain your class.
- You did not import the Verbatims class on the referencing script.

**Fix for 3rd option should be like this:**

```
 <script type="module">
  import {Verbatims} from './src/vebatim.js';

   ....ommitted for brevity

  changeNbRequest = function() {
            var timer = setInterval(function() {
                let verbatim = new Verbatims().list()[ite];
            }, 5000);
  }
 </script>
```

**Additional TIP**

To improve your code, try to place all the JS code inside your index.html to an external file so you can take advantage of ES6 import/export features.

Comment: So my file is loading in the browser, and it contains my class. So your third option but now my browser doesn't load my vue ...

Comment: I already try to place my js code in an external file but then it didn't recognize my class Vue